# Polymer 1.0 + Webpack

Tags: javascript, polymer, webpack, polymer-1.0

Currently I am trying to use Webpack (http://webpack.github.io/) as my module builder and wanted to see if anyone has done this yet with Polymer v1.0.  There is a webpack loader called polymer-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/polymer-loader) but it does not work with anything higher than Polymer v0.5.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried. What was your expected result, what actually happened?

Comment: He has tried `polymer-loader`. as he said, it works with Polymer 0.5, but not 1.0.

Comment: The loader is broken because of the API change in 1.0 & 0.8, and unfortunately nobody is going to fix it as no PR queued so far. May be you can start without loader first: require the component js files & assets as general js files do, then npm install the libraries and setup the config file.

Comment: The last update to polymer-loader (https://www.npmjs.com/package/polymer-loader) was pushed at least 3 months before Polymer 1.0 was published (http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/05/polymer-10-released.html)

Comment: I've built a package to handle polymer/webcomponents files and html imports (with code reload support)

https://github.com/aruntk/wc-loader. check out.

Demo https://github.com/aruntk/polymer-webpack-demo

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Polymer 1.0 is presently unsupported by `polymer-loader` due to an API change. It is possible that this may be repaired in the near future, but in the meantime you may have to resort to either a different package or builder. Hopefully a fix becomes available soon.

Comment: Thank god. Who on earth wants to use Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

I make a simple solution with [polymer-ext](https://github.com/yutingzhao1991/polymer-ext)

```
var PolymerExt = require('polymer-ext')

var t = require('raw!./test.tmpl')
var s = require('raw!./test.css')

PolymerExt({
  is: 'card-panel',
  template: t,
  style: s,
  ... // other polymer options
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just succeeded by means of this loader:

https://github.com/aitoroses/vulcanize-loader

Unobvious thing is that i had to install the webcomponent that i wanted through bower (yarn does the job too). After that, manually reference it inside manually created `importer.html` file, and then at the end, reference that `importer.html` file inside your js module:

```
import 'vulcanize!./importer.html';
```